# Customization of modules, constants, and databases in a settings / config file for Flask

Tags: python, settings, flask

I've been playing around with Flask for the past week. For fun, I'm trying to implement the following. Yes, I know it's very Django-esque, and perhaps inappropriate for a micro-framework.

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
STATIC_PATH = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_URL = '/template/'
DATABASES = {
  'DEBUG': {
    'ENGINE': 'bla.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'koopics.db'
  },
  'DEMO': {
    'ENGINE': 'bla.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'somedb'
  },
  'PRODUCTION': {
    'ENGINE': 'bla.psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'somedb',
    'host': 'host',
    'username': 'host',
    'password': 'host',
  },
}

MODE = 'Demo'

#TODO: put an IF statement here to provide  the connection mechanism for the db
#      depending on what is required    

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'Flask-SQLAlchemy',
  'Flask-DebugToolbar',
  'Flask-Mail',
  'Flask-Cache',
  'Flask-Celery',
  'my_custom_module',
]
```

I currently have my custom apps defined in their own folder with `__init__.py`.

**Question:** Is it possible to get the DBs to work and have the "apps" loaded as part of settings and app.py?

Comment: you've forgotten to say "what is required" ...

Answer (score 1):

Your settings are loaded first, before anything else is processed. If you want to switch DBs depending on a request, then you need to put this `if` in the model/view logic.

According to the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/binds.html) (your settings look much more like `django` than regular `flask` so I'm not sure that this will even work) you can use `__bind_key__` in your models to direct that model to a particular DB

```
# settings.py
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'DEBUG': 'sqlite:////path/to/koopics.db',
    'DEMO': 'sqlite:////path/to/somedb.db'
}
```

and in you model

```
# model
class DebugModel(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'DEBUG'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    debug_value = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

However, if you mean that you want this to access the DB one way for say production, and another for development, then something like

```
import os

if os.environ('MACHINE_NAME', '') == 'PRODUCTION':
    # set up production db
else:
    # set up development db
```

then an `if` in your settings is appropriate.